# Errors when trying to run an AWSPowerShellModuleScript@1 in Azure devops pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, powershell, azure-devops, yaml

I currently have an Azure Devops pipeline to build and deploy a next.js application via the serverless framework.

Upon reaching the AWSPowerShellModuleScript@1 task I get these errors:

- [warning]MSG:UnableToDownload «https:...» «»
- [warning]Unable to download the list of available providers. Check
  your internet connection.
- [warning]Unable to download from URI 'https:...' to ''.
- [error]No match was found for the specified search criteria for the
  provider 'NuGet'. The package provider requires 'PackageManagement'
  and 'Provider' tags. Please check if the specified package has the
  tags.
- [error]No match was found for the specified search criteria and
  module name 'AWSPowerShell'. Try Get-PSRepository to see all
  available registered module repositories.
- [error]The specified module 'AWSPowerShell' was not loaded because no
  valid module file was found in any module directory.

I do have the AWS.ToolKit installed and it's visible when I go to manage extensions within Azure Devops.

My pipeline:

```
trigger: none

stages:
- stage: develop_build_deploy_stage
  pool:
    name: Default
    demands:
      - msbuild
      - visualstudio

  jobs:
  - job: develop_build_deploy_job
    steps:
    - checkout: self
      clean: true

    - task: NodeTool@0
      displayName: Install Node    
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '12.x'
    - script: |
        npm install
        npx next build    
      displayName: Install Dependencies and Build

    - task: CopyFiles@2
      inputs:
        Contents: 'build/**'
        TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      displayName: Publish Artifact
      inputs: 
        pathtoPublish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
        artifactName: dev_artifacts

    - task: AWSPowerShellModuleScript@1
      displayName: Deploy to Lambda@Edge
      inputs:
        awsCredentials: '###'
        regionName: '###'
        scriptType: 'inline'
        inlineScript: 'npx serverless --package dev_artifacts'
```

I know I can use the ubuntu vmImage and then make use of the awsShellScript but the build agent I have available to me doesn't support bash.

Comment: You can try to add `Install-Module` and `import-module` command manually in the script . `Install-Module -Name AWSPowerShell` .Here is a [reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/userguide/pstools-getting-set-up-windows.html).

Comment: Thank you for the response. The missing module turned out to be the problem and our build agent was running an older version of powershell so it wasn't able to resolve it automatically.